# Best method to have a popup menu in Android

Tags: android

I need help as I am a bit stuck.
I want to know what is the best method to implement for what I want in my app. I want the user to be able to click on an image in a page, and a popup menu appears. The user would have a selction of 5 items, and they would be able to click on one of them and the app would go to the selected menut item/page.
I have a popup Menu that works, but I am not able to style it. I have asked about it, but the answers seem to be that it is not possible to do so.
I have also implemented a PopupWindow, but although the items appear as a list, it is not possible to select them.

Would someone advice me as to what is the best to implement? 
Thanks very much. I can post both sets of code: for PopupMenu and PopupWindow, if that helps.

Comment: If your question is specifically how to **style** a popup menu, you need to make that very clear because it is buried towards the end of your post. And no, you cannot style context menus.

Comment: If you want to style it, create a Dialog or DialogFragment, where you create the layout for the menu yourself.

Comment: Hi Grennis. My question is really about what is the best method to show what one would call in 'normal' language a popup menu, and that whatever method it is, to be able to style it. What other menus are there, that on clicking an image, a 'popup' menu apears, and the user selects one item from the menu?

Comment: Rick, thanks for the comment. I have read on Dialog and it is not clear to me if the user is able to select on one of the items presented. Do you know?